# MySQL: Is there a performance hit comparing numbers with an important precision

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering in MySQL if it is better for performance to compare numbers with an important precision or to round them before comparing, knowing that the comparison precision is less important than the compared numbers precision.

Ex:

```
SELECT 0.123456789101112123456789101112 < 0.987654321012345987654321012345
```

OR

```
SELECT ROUND(0.123456789101112123456789101112,2) < ROUND(0.987654321012345987654321012345,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's clearly a performance hit in the version that uses `ROUND()`.

First, calling a function will always be more expensive than not calling a function.

Second, and possibly more significantly, if there's an index on the column, it can't be used if you perform a function on the column before comparing it with something.

But getting the right answer is practically always more important than using the most efficient method.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question by adding a precision of 2 in the ROUND version.

Comment: The precision is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Yes but it was the example i wanted to give at the origin.